# Jquery Условие на класс

Tags: jquery

Уважаемые жители Стака прошу совета.

есть код. 
    
                    Заявка родителя
                    Заявка соискателя

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('li').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.bbd').addClass('acc')
  } else {
    $('.bbd').removeClass('acc')
  }
});
```

```css
.acc {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #024a78;
}
.acc:link,
.acc:visited,
.acc:hover,
.acc:active{
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #024a78;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs borders">
  <li class="semi active">
    <a href="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab">
      <span class="bbd">Заявка родителя</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="semi">
    <a href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab">
      <span class="bbd">Заявка соискателя</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Нужно что бы при активности, появлялся бордерботтом.

Comment: что не так с твоим кодом? в чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: по клику необходимо добавлять активный класс?

Comment: какой "активности"? пишите подробнее

Comment: ребята , спасибо,  в след раз буду писать более развернуто, решение мне помогло Eugene Eray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используя телепатический модуль сообщаю, вам гораздо проще будет убрать этот класс у всех, а потом, добавить класс к потомку li с классом active.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li .bbd').removeClass('acc');
  $('li.active .bbd').addClass('acc');

});
```

```css
.acc {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #024a78;
}
.acc:link,
.acc:visited,
.acc:hover,
.acc:active{
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #024a78;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs borders">
  <li class="semi active">
    <a href="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab">
      <span class="bbd">Заявка родителя</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="semi">
    <a href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab">
      <span class="bbd">Заявка соискателя</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: У вас есть хрустальный шар?)

Comment: не, у меня система Муад-Диб.

Comment: Тогда уважаю :-D +1

Answer (score 1):

Знаю вот такой вариант

```js
$("li .bbd").click(function(){ 
   $("li .bbd").each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("acc");
   });
      $(this).addClass("acc");
 });
```

```css
.acc {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #024a78;
}
.acc:link,
.acc:visited,
.acc:hover,
.acc:active{
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #024a78;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs borders">
  <li class="semi active">
    <a href="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab">
      <span class="bbd">Заявка родителя</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="semi">
    <a href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab">
      <span class="bbd">Заявка соискателя</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: спасибо друг мой